# Does anyone have jade template language working in brunch?

Tags: node.js, pug, brunch

Anyone got jade templets working with brunch? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using it

1. Add to /package.json

   ```
   "dependencies":{
      ...
      "jade-brunch":"> 1.0 < 1.4",
      ...
   },
   ```
2. Create your templates in */app/views/templates*. Should be ended with **.jade**
3. Run commands

   ```
   cd <App>
   npm install
   brunch build
   ```

Comment: seriously are you guys able to run jade and get it to show with just these steps? Nothing shows up on my end - i see my Jade template content being compiled into app.js but it doesn't show up on the front end.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that's it's compliant (on [Brucn Homepage](http://brunch.io/)):

> Pre-compiled templates: Handlebars.js, Jade, Mustache, Eco

Seems like you have to do that (on [first page of documentation](http://brunch.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-change-app-language)), obviously replacing eco to jade:

> Remove "handlebars-brunch": "version" line from package.json.
>   Add "eco-brunch": "version" there
>   Change config.files.templates.defaultExtension to eco in config.coffee.

Seems like you have a [RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rtfm) problem.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how, but I missed it too:)

Comment: please tell me what im missing here - i'm trying to run jade. package-json - http://d.pr/i/ypuS and config.coffee - http://d.pr/i/r8CW